# The view count of a question: Counting on the valid account or the valid IP address

Tags: discussion

When we see the number on the number count of views (such as 8K view) on a question:

Is that number counting based on the valid account or the valid IP address?

If that is based on the valid IP address, then it does not require a register account to count for the number of views?